# C# - Retrieve Default Headers from Response - [HttpClient ]

Tags: c#, header, httpclient

Is there any way of getting all the headers from the HttpClient request just like we can do it with the headers of the HttpResponseMessage?

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com/").Result) {
    HttpResponseHeaders headers = response.Headers;
}
```

This will works great getting all the headers of the response, but how we do it for the httpclient itself? Thanks!

Is HttpWebRequest the only way?

Comment: You can do something like this 
                `var client = new HttpClient();`
               `var response =  client.GetAsync (url).Result;`
                `var content = response.Headers;`

Comment: Not all the properties are easily accessible.  If you create a custom class that inherits the WebRequest you can get access to more of the properties.

Comment: @WilliamHan This will get the headers of the response, not the request method.

Comment: How about `response.RequestMessage.Headers`

Comment: @WilliamHan It will work the same as using client.DefaultRequestHeaders, it only returns the header I add manually the client. If I don't add a custom header property to the client's header it will return nothing. That's what I dislike about the HttpClient... I think I will switch back to the HttpWebRequest, even though it will completely break the performance and my plans. Thanks Microsoft!